# How to select * from table when group by?

Tags: ms-access, group-by

```
select 
    OrderNo, 
    Sum(QtyIn) as QuantityIn, 
    Sum(QtyOut) as QuantityOut 
from 
    tbl_Assign 
group by 
    OrderNo
```

I want to select * from table also group by from table. How to do it?

Comment: What do you think should be returned for columns that are not grouped then?

Comment: I want to show all columns from table that all should grouped

Comment: You want to group by ALL columns?

Comment: Yes @DavidG You are right

Comment: Can you define what is `*`? And what kind of `Sum` do you expect?

Comment: * is all columns. and sum of quantity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group by on all columns with a sum you cannot use `*`, you have to list all of the columns out and every column that isn't a function like Sum must be included in the group by.

So if you have other fields in your database such as OrderName, OrderedBy you can perform a group by like this:

```
Select
  OrderNo,
  OrderName,
  OrderBy,
  Sum(QtyIn) as QuantityIn,
  Sum(QtyOut) as QuantityOut
From
  tbl_Assign
Group By
   OrderNo, OrderName, OrderBy
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will create one row for every row in the tbl_Assign.
Each row will also show the summary information for the order.

This might not be what you need, but it's useful to understand it anyway.

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.* 
FROM 
    ( select * FROM tbl_Assign ) AS T1
    LEFT JOIN ( select 
                    OrderNo, 
                    Sum(QtyIn) as QuantityIn, 
                    Sum(QtyOut) as QuantityOut 
                from 
                    tbl_Assign 
                group by 
                    OrderNo
               ) AS T2
    ON T1.OrderNo = T2.OrderNo
```

Harvey